# image gallery pop-up swipes to every other image

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, image-gallery, swipe

I have built my first jQuery mobile image gallery, but I have a bug I can't seem to fix. When an image is tapped it pops up to full screen and to carousel all the images I can swipe the images or tap prev/next arrows.

Edit: The problem has changed slightly since I wrote this question, therefor I need to make a few changes in my question and my code.

The images now swipe to every other image, according to the order they are shown in the gallery. I'm dynamically adding a data-index to each image, but somehow the result is tabindex="0" for each image that pops up.

```
   <body>
        <!-- gallery content -->
        <div data-role="content" id="pagecontent" class="gallerycontent">
    <a href="#imgshow" data-transition="pop" data-rel="dialog">
        <img src="../img/someimage.jpg" alt="someimage.jpg"/>
        </a>
            <!-- plus more unordered images -->
        </div> <!--/content-->
    </div><!-- /page -->

<!-- full screen image preview -->
    <div data-role="dialog"  id="imgshow"  data-theme="d">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
            <div id="dialoghead"></div>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
            <center><div id="dialogcontent"></div></center>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <center>
                <a href="#" id="prevbtn" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="arrow-l">Previous</a>
                <a href="#" id="nextbtn" data-role="button" data-iconpos="notext" data-icon="arrow-r">Next</a>
            </center>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</body>
```

The 'on-touch' function and 'gonext' function in jquery.

```
//on-touch function
    $('.gallerycontent img').bind('tap',function(event, ui){

        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
        $('#dialogcontent').empty().append('<a href="#galleryImg"><img src="' + src + '" style="width:100%;"/></a>' );
        $('#dialoghead').empty().append('<center><h2>' + alt + '</h2></center>' );
        $(this).parent().addClass('selectedimg');
    });
function gonext() {
        var current = $('a.selectedimg');
        if (current.hasClass('last')) {
        var next = $('a.first')
        } else {
        var next = current.next();
        }

        var src = next.find('img').attr("src");
        var alt = next.find('img').attr("alt");
        next.addClass('selectedimg');
        current.removeClass('selectedimg');
        $('#dialogcontent').empty().append('<a href="#gallerypage"><img src="' + src + '" style="width:100%;"/></a>' );
        $('#dialoghead').empty().append('<center><h2>' + alt + '</h2></center>' );
}
```

Any thought or hints?

Comment: I followed this tutorial to build the gallery in the first place: http://www.irinavelychko.com/tutorials/jquery-mobile-gallery#more-20

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that the `selectedimg` class isn't being removed when the popup is opened. Try adding this line

```
$('.selectedimg').removeClass('selectedimg');
```

just before the addClass line into this function, like this:

```
//on-touch function
$('.gallerycontent img').bind('tap',function(event, ui){
    var src = $(this).attr("src");
    var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
    $('#dialogcontent').empty().append('<a href="#galleryImg"><img src="' + src + '" style="width:100%;"/></a>' );
    $('#dialoghead').empty().append('<center><h2>' + alt + '</h2></center>' );
    $('.selectedimg').removeClass('selectedimg');
    $(this).parent().addClass('selectedimg');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't change anything.